# PHP Startup Error

Tags: php, ubuntu, web-applications, suse

I have a website running mysql and apache on Ubuntu (where it works), windows (where it works), ans suse where it doesn't. I am trying to run an artisan migration using php and I get the following error (it also errors out on anything dealing with php). I trying updating everything, and I was told it might be something in my php.ini file, but I haven't found anything pointing to that because it works on the other machines. Also I can't just comment them out as many of these are necessary.

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/extensions/bcmath.so' - /usr/lib/php5/extensions/bcmath.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/extensions/bz2.so' - /usr/lib/php5/extensions/bz2.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/extensions/calendar.so' - /usr/lib/php5/extensions/calendar.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/extensions/ctype.so' - /usr/lib/php5/extensions/ctype.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/extensions/fileinfo.so' - /usr/lib/php5/extensions/fileinfo.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/extensions/json.so' - /usr/lib/php5/extensions/json.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/extensions/mbstring.so' - /usr/lib/php5/extensions/mbstring.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/extensions/mcrypt.so' - /usr/lib/php5/extensions/mcrypt.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/extensions/mysql.so' - /usr/lib/php5/extensions/mysql.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/extensions/mysqli.so' - /usr/lib/php5/extensions/mysqli.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/extensions/openssl.so' - /usr/lib/php5/extensions/openssl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/extensions/pdo.so' - /usr/lib/php5/extensions/pdo.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/extensions/pdo_mysql.so' - /usr/lib/php5/extensions/pdo_mysql.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/extensions/tokenizer.so' - /usr/lib/php5/extensions/tokenizer.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/extensions/xmlwriter.so' - /usr/lib/php5/extensions/xmlwriter.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/extensions/zip.so' - /usr/lib/php5/extensions/zip.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/extensions/zlib.so' - /usr/lib/php5/extensions/zlib.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
Could not open input file: phpinfo
```

**EDIT:**

It seems the directory is empty, any ideas on how to restore it?

Comment: Do those files exist at that location?  ( /usr/lib/php5/extensions/ )

Comment: No, but they don't repopulate when I update. Any idea on how to restore them?

Comment: i don't use SUSE but i believe the command to specify what modules to include is like  (modify to suit which modules you require);
yast2 -i php5-mysql php5-bcmath php5-bz2 php5-calendar php5-ctype php5-curl php5-dom php5-ftp php5-gd php5-gettext php5-gmp php5-iconv php5-imap php5-ldap php5-mbstring php5-mcrypt php5-odbc php5-openssl php5-pcntl php5-pgsql php5-posix php5-shmop php5-snmp php5-soap php5-sockets php5-sqlite php5-sysvsem php5-tokenizer php5-wddx php5-xmlrpc php5-xsl php5-zlib php5-exif php5-fastcgi php5-pear

Comment: unless you use zypper to install, in which case (and add whichever other modules you need);
zypper install -y apache2 apache2-mod_perl apache2-mod_php5 php5 php5-mbstring php5-pear

Comment: I get error saying the dependency trees are unavailable for those. I have the option of uninstalling things or not grabbing the packages (for all of the options) I'm not sure how to copy paste the exact error from the yast interface. Is it possible that these .so files are being stalled somewhere else by default?